# Attach file from the server into email

Tags: php, email-attachments

can anyone give me some idea how to attach a file from the server and send it as attachment through email?? 
i have the following code:

```
<?php 
// Read POST request params into global vars 
$to      = $_POST['to'];
$from    = $_POST['from'];
$subject = $_POST['subject']; 
$message = $_POST['message'];
// Obtain file upload vars
$fileatt      = $_FILES['fileatt']['tmp_name']; 
$fileatt_type = $_FILES['fileatt']['type'];
$fileatt_name = $_FILES['fileatt']['name'];
$headers = "From: $from";  
if (is_uploaded_file($fileatt)) {
// Read the file to be attached ('rb' = read binary)
$file = fopen($fileatt,'rb'); 
$data = fread($file,filesize($fileatt)); 
fclose($file);
// Generate a boundary string 
$semi_rand = md5(time());
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
// Add the headers for a file attachment  
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
        "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . 
        " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 
// Add a multipart boundary above the plain message 
 $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . 
"--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . 
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .   
$message . "\n\n"; 
// Base64 encode the file data 
// Add file attachment to the message 
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
"Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n" .
 " name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" . 
//"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . 
//" filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .              
          $data . "\n\n" .  "--{$mime_boundary}--\n"; 
}
// Send the message 
$ok = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
if ($ok) { 
echo "<p>Mail sent! Yay PHP!</p>"; 
} else { 
echo "<p>Mail could not be sent. Sorry!</p>"; 
}
?>
```

but this code does not attach file from the server.
please help me out.. thanks in advance..!!

Comment: Where is your code to add files which are located on the server? You check with _is_uploaded_file_ whether you uploaded the file. So you can't add a file from server.

Comment: Hi lspcity..!! 
Thnk u so mch for your help..!!
Well, the problem is solved.. Previously, i was just uploading the file to the server..  The problem solved when i inserted the file into database and retrieved it while mailing the file as attachment.. Here's the code:

$sql12="select * from drafts where path='$path'";       $result=mysql_query($sql12);     $curr_file = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$fileatt_size = $curr_file['File_Size'];
$fileatt_type = $curr_file['File_Type'];
$fileatt_name = $curr_file['File_Name'];
$data = $curr_file['File_Content'];

Thnk u so mch once again..!!

Answer (score 0):

One question: Do you want to send e-mails with attachment or do you want to improve your PHP skills with this problem?

If you only want to send mails, have a look at [PHPMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/files/phpmailer%20for%20php5_6/PHPMailer%20v5.1/) which is very good and easily to handle. For myself I'm using this for years without problems.

For improving your skills: You say that the attachment is encoded in base64, but I cannot find the line where you do something like **$data = base64_encode($data);** You add the *$data* of your attachment in plain to the mail.

Comment: yeah.. m sorry.. i missed that line while pasting the code here..
The code goes like this..

$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
 "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
 " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

Everything is working just fine n im able to send emails with attachments.. The problem im facing is when i try to attach files from the server..